# Ajax interactive map

Tags: jquery, ajax, dictionary, interactive

I'm new to this forum and new to jquery and ajax. So, I'm trying to create an interactive map. However, next to the map there's going to be a form (e.g. with checkboxes). Say, we have a map of europe and a form with options such as "has sea" or "has english as main language" or "has more than [user defined value] citizens" and so on. When the user selects an option, a query is made to the database finding all the countries that fulfill the selected criteria. Then, these countries are highlighted on the map and they are clickable while the other ones are not. I want this to happen without reloading the page so I'll have to use ajax and maybe jquery with SVG maps. Is that right? Are there any other solutions?

The question is, is there something modifiable on the internet? I googled it but didn't find anything quite similar. As I said I have little experience in ajax and jquery so I cannot start it from scratch.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Google Maps already does this, therefore it's possible.

Comment: Just so you know. You may be biting a bit more than you can chew if you are just starting out with programming. Ive been coding for years and would never think I could do a project like that.

Comment: The link in joao cunha's comment, under his answer, is going to be your best starting point.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/) provides the functionality you're after. You may want to take a closer look at the Overlay and Layers classes which provides you sort of drawing capabilities on the map (like a poligon covering an area).

Also, you will need to have all your data in a separate place, as Google Maps API doesn't provide any data at all.

I don't agree with @thatidiotguy as this doesn't look so difficult.

1. create a polygon covering the specified region;
2. place a clickable Marker on that country to display any other
   relevant information.

Good luck :)

Comment: Regarding your first point, of creating a polygon, do you know how many points it takes to define the border of a country? You also need to take account of when the map is zoomed.

Comment: You're right as I don't know how he could actually find all those points - and if they can be found. But it's pretty straightforward to identify places, as you can see here: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/country_explorer/country_explorer.html

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the **Google Geochart API** instead. I think it will look better visually, and it's easier to highlight the countries. 
If you're database is well built, it's not that difficult to build interactive maps on the fly. I've built a wp plugin with the geochart API and on the backend I have a big form so user can input data and ech time he changes a field the preview of the map changes on the fly. So, very similar to what you want to do. 
Check out the api here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

and, so you have an idea of what i was able to do with it: 
http://cmoreira.net/interactive-world-maps-demo/administration-screenshots/

Hope it helps!
Cheers